# Manufacturer attribute is not working on advanced search page

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-attributes, dropdown-attribute, advanced-search

[image]I have added manufacturer attribute in advanced search page. when i am searching product by manufacturer its showing error You have to specify at least one search term. but when i am searching with category then its working fine.

If i am going to search only by Manufacturer then i am facing an error message like “You have to specify at least one search term”.

[image]

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara i have shared my screenshot can you check please

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara.. when am i searching with any drop down attribute then i am facing an error “You have to specify at least one search term”.

Comment: Yes. i have just found your screenshot. Thanks for sharing. 1)  At attribute properties section, please select the scope as Global and select apply to all products instead of selected products. 2) at Front end properties, select Yes at use in search results layered navigation to yes instead of No. 3) reindex the all data and remove the cache.

Comment: have you done the changes?

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara... yes just now but its still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47917/discussion-between-er-sarvesh-v-tiwari-and-teja-bhagavan-kollepara).

Answer (score 0):

From the admin Manage attributes, select your custom attribute `manufacturer` and in the Frontend Properties, select `Use in Advanced Search => YES`

Then, you will be able to display the attribute in advance search results

Comment: ...i have done this so attribute is showing in frontend please read full question before answering i am getting error when am i searching ...

Comment: when am i searching with manufacturer value it getting error ....as like You have to specify at least one search term

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the following to get the reason :

1. The manufacturer attribute was not assigned to any of your store's Attribute sets.
2. The attribute value does not assigned at product.
3. May be there have some custom code at which override the feature of
   advance search.

You need to fixed them.

Comment: i have assigned manufacturer at Attribute sets and also assigned value in product

Comment: If i am going to search only by Manufacturer then i am facing an error message like “You have to specify at least one search term”.